# How create type guard for path with dynamic field?

Tags: typescript

I have a field that can contain both a schema and an object in which this schema lies by key, depending on the situation

How should looks a guard be able to solve this problem?

Here is example of my code

```
import * as z from 'zod';
import type { ZodTypeAny } from 'zod'

type Key = 'test' | 'test2' | 'test3'

type Schema = {
  schema?: ZodTypeAny |  {
    [Property in Key]?: ZodTypeAny
  }
}

const userSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  email: z.string(),
});


const getSchema = (key: Key, path: Schema) {
  return path.schema?.[key] || path.schema
}

getSchema('test', { schema: {'test':  userSchema}})
getSchema('test', { schema: userSchema})
```

and of course you can test it in TS payground
[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wF5wGZQiOAcgwgBNCBuAKFEljhgE8wBTOAbzgC0yAVZlgEEAdozgBfHHgLEyhKlSas4AaRZiAvERgtUMQnAA%2023TABMB44R16AzPMUC4AZQDGACxYhkcLeypwcKgeXsgA-ABc3HwCImLGHAGBcADaAAp4rLBiwMKq6gC6kdGk-KxxSeJUVVSuEMJ6cACuqCxQbp7evpgAdBAARgBWLK4wABT%20gcLIICxRGD16ULkA5mMAlAA0SaHAADbzizDLwmtb1evUCnUN8CssMB2h3WMA1upRaoybcGDIMO4ok9vOtEoEoA8mlA8n8AYsQt4wj0Uu9GAUjMZYe54Z1kNUFPdHgjkGNrKZCD9OMFcVF2GS9IQos1Wu1ieJxOsqITgST6fpKUFiVEWm0eRygA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a type predicate to check if `schema` is `ZodType<any, any, any>`. Something like this

```
const isSchemaZodType = (schema: unknown): schema is ZodTypeAny => schema instanceof z.ZodType<any, any, any>
```

and then use it like this

```
const getSchema = (key: Key, path: Schema) => {
  if (!path.schema) {
    return path
  }

  if (isSchemaZodType(path.schema)) {
    return path.schema
  }

  return path.schema[key]
}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wF5wGZQiOAcgwgBNCBuAKFEljhgE8wBTOAbzgC0yAVZlgEEAdozgBfHHgLEyhKlSas4AaRZiAvERgtUMQnAA+23TABMB44R16AzPMUC4AZQDGACxYhkcLeypwcKgeXsgA-ABc3HwCImLGHAGBcADaAAp4rLBiwMKq6gC6kdGk-KxxSeJUVVSuEMJ6cACuqCxQbp7evpgAdBAARgBWLK4wABT+gcLIICxRGD16ULkA5mMAlAA0SaHAADbzizDLwmtb1evUtfWNwKgdoTylTlpjwZ3IUU3CANbCEAB3YTrKLvUJwO4lMpCUS+AB8QRCXVyemQwlcLAg2F6T2hAB40YxNihRMTCXCFHUGvAViwYA8uq8fuoomoiXAwMgYO4ogzkOt4YlAsBsWMAISc7mLJH8oXJKB0ppQPKS9yVBTC0V3Pm4gRjVXSj7rAWTeWK5UcrnuQ2hdVJBUwJUqq027wpZmMArVBS0+kysbWUyEYmcMHeKLsQN6QhRZqtdoy8TidZUX18gM2fQhxEfL7xvnJoA)

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with Zod but I believe this captures your intent:

```
import * as z from 'zod';
import type { ZodTypeAny } from 'zod'

type Key = 'test' | 'test2' | 'test3'

type SchemaObject = {
    [Property in Key]?: ZodTypeAny
}

type Schema = {
  schema?: ZodTypeAny | SchemaObject
}

const userSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  email: z.string(),
});

function isSchemaObject(z: Schema['schema']): z is SchemaObject {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(z, 'test')
    || Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(z, 'test2') 
    || Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(z, 'test3') 
}

const getSchema = (key: Key, path: Schema) => {
  const schema = path.schema;
  return isSchemaObject(schema) ? schema[key] : schema
}

getSchema('test', { schema: {'test':  userSchema}})
getSchema('test', { schema: userSchema})
```

So we create a `SchemaObject` type to simplify referring to it, and then use a type guard `isSchemaObject` to check which of the components of the union type the value is.